# How to execute g++ code and run it as well using execl

Tags: command-line, executable, g++

I am writing a program in c++ that uses fork and then child program do execl which opens xterm and execute another program let's say p2code. Here is what I am doing

```
execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "/usr/bin/xterm","-e","g++ /Desktop/assignment/p2code.cpp -o asd","/Desktop/assignment/./asd",(void*)NULL);
```

This opens the xterm as shown in the screenshot below but it doesn't compile p2code nor execute "asd". 
I am trying my best to learn execl. I opened its man page as well but I am not getting it. Kindly help me understand it. Thanks in advance.
[image: Xterm Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the path of the source file. You are giving absolute path of the file, i.e. `/Desktop/assignment/p2code.cpp` but I think your source file is located at `~/Desktop/assignment`. Also, your `xterm` is currently in `~/Desktop/assignment` directory. And I assume that there is no folder like `Desktop` in `/` directory. So, replace `/Desktop/assignment/p2code.cpp` with `~/Desktop/assignment/p2code.cpp`(if you want to give absolute path) or source file name, i.e. `p2code.cpp`(since `xterm` is currently in the directory where source file is located).